# Why is moviepy.editor giving ffmpeg not found error when I import ffmpeg?

Tags: python

```
#from pytube import YouTube as YT #How to get video.mp4
'''
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JC-EGagoM3k'
vid = YT(url)
Streams = vid.streams

filtered = vid.streams.filter(progressive = True, mime_type = 'video/mp4')
filtered.get_highest_resolution().download(filename = 'Video.mp4')
'''

import ffmpeg
import moviepy
from moviepy.editor import *

clip = (VideoFileClip('Video.mp4').subclip((1,22),(1,23)).rotate(180))
screenshot = clip.crop(x2 = clip.w/2).to_ImageClip(0.2).set_duration(clip.duration)
c = CompositeVideoClip([clip,screenshot])
clip.write_gif('clip.gif')
```

When I run this it shows :
[image: This Error]

Even after I imported ffmpeg any ideas on why moviepy.editor doing this?

Comment: What you've successfully installed and imported via `import ffmpeg` is just a Python module for talking to the "ffmpeg" application.  *That's* what you haven't installed, or at least don't have installed in the place where the module is looking for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  :

```
import os
os.environ["IMAGEIO_FFMPEG_EXE"] = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg"
```

before importing moviepy  `import moviepy`

**NOTE :** this is [bug](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/1158) in `moviepy` it will be fixed in the next version

Comment: What about on Replit?

Comment: Are you using **Replit** online ide ?

Comment: Yes I am using Replit IDE

Comment: change `"/usr/bin/ffmpeg"` to where **ffmpeg** is located in your envorenment   on Replit it goes somthing like this `/home/runner/<name of your project/venv /lib/...`

Comment: Wait what’s after lib? I can’t find the file…

Comment: it depends on your project . just select **Files** in the top left corner you will find 3 dots click there and **show hidden files** you'll get your folder and look for the path to **ffmpeg**   and use it instead of `"/usr/bin/ffmpeg"`

Comment: Alright it’s says er o file no found tho but thanks! Any other help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would be better  to us  vscode editor . It will help you manage your project more easily. Sorry for not  fixing your error